# How to specify `--asg-access` in config file with eksctl?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, eksctl

I am trying to create a Kubernetes on AWS EKS cluster using `eksctl` with autoscaling enabled using proper IAM permissions. As per the [documentation](https://eksctl.io/usage/autoscaling/):

> You can create a cluster (or nodegroup in an existing cluster) with
>   IAM role that will allow use of cluster autoscaler:
>
> `eksctl create cluster --asg-access`

I am trying to run

```
eksctl create cluster --asg-access -f myconfig.yml
```

But getting this error:

```
[✖]  cannot use --asg-access when --config-file/-f is set
```

Is their a way to use `--asg-access` within the config file? I try to look for a related config in the [config file schema doc](https://eksctl.io/usage/schema/) to no avail.

Answer (score 23):

You can enable autoscaling within config file without passing `asg-access` flag, i.e.

```
iam:
  withAddonPolicies:
    autoScaler: true
```

[Example](https://github.com/weaveworks/eksctl/blob/a9e7c0694ada09802bd8dd707766de3923816510/examples/05-advanced-nodegroups.yaml#L21)

Hope this will help

Comment: Thanks, that's on the nodegroup level, but is it possible on the cluster level?

Comment: @PierreB I don't think you can make it on cluster level.

Comment: I ended-up doing it on the nodegroup level as you suggested